# Standard term for "area between a tangent to a hyperbola and its two asymptotes"?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections

Is there a standard concise term for:

- the property of a hyperbola that is the (constant) area of a triangle defined by any tangent and the two asymptotes (equivalently: one quarter of the product of minor and major axis lengths), or
- anything related to said area by a constant factor, like half or twice?